# vagrant up command throwing ssl error

Tags: vagrant

Looks like the error originates because I'm behind company firewall, at least that's my theory.

I have tried tried the option suggested in the error message and running vagrant up with *--insecure* flag, but that's not the option for the *up* command, but only for *add* command. However I already have a Vagrantfile and all the corresponding config so I only need to run vagrant up. What's the solution here?

```
vagrant up

    Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> default: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and in
    stall...
        default: Box Provider: virtualbox
        default: Box Version: >= 0
    The box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found or
    could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
    box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
    `vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
    URL and error message are shown below:

    URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64"]
    Error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

    curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
     of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
     bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
     using the --cacert option.
    If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
     the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
     problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
     not match the domain name in the URL).
    If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
     the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

sdfsdf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might need to run in 2 steps.

1. download the box using the `insecure` flag

   ```
   vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64 --insecure
   ```
2. spin up your VM

   ```
   vagrant up
   ```

Comment: In your Vangrant file

Comment: where exactly to add ? which file of which dir ? Is it in `vagrant-boxes\OracleDatabase\19.3.0`

Answer (score 16):

```
config.vm.box_download_insecure = true #added by Amos for curl error
```

Comment: It was a bit difficult for a newbie like me to figure out where exactly to add this.  
But after opening and editing all vagrant related files in cloned directories, I could figure it out.  <br/>


To help people like me, we need to add this line in Vagrant file (named Vagrantfile) present in cloned directory (vagrant-boxes\OracleDatabase\XX.X.X)  <br/>


And then just save and run `vagrant up`, this resolved my error

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific box version, please use

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead --insecure --box-version=12.1.0 --provider=virtualbox
```